# Doctrine ArrayCollection: why it uses isset($this->elements[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $this->elements): aren't they the same thing?

Tags: php

A bit long title :P

Anyway, in the `ArrayCollection` class, Doctrine uses this syntax to check if a `Collection` contains the given key:

```
public function containsKey($key)
{
    return isset($this->elements[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $this->elements);
}
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L199-L202).

Why both `isset` and `array_key_exists` are used? Aren't them the same thing in this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, No. They are not the same. From [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

> `isset()` does not return **TRUE** for array keys that correspond to a
>   **NULL** value, while `array_key_exists()` does.

Comment: Ok, but why not use `array_key_exists()` alone? Why adding also `isset()`?

Comment: I could only think of one reason: `isset()` is much more faster on large array inputs than `array_key_exists()` hence their order.

Comment: Yes, it is reasonable... Thank you! I've learned another trick! :D

Answer (score 0):

`array_key_exists()` makes sure the entry exists in the array

`isset()` makes sure the entry is not null (which also acts as an existence check, since if it has a non-null value, it obviously is in the array)

The reason `isset()` is used first in a function specifically looking for the existence of a key is that it is faster on larger arrays. So the function basically assumes that if the key exists, that it will have a non-null value, and if it does not find it, it then double checks the array using the slower `array_key_exists()`.